# How to autowire in runtime for dynamic service class and method name

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a project going on in which kafka consumers code is responsible for calling a business service and method.
All this work fine until where the service class has autowired services.
Those autowiring fails with NPE.

I understand that calling the service outside of spring IOC will not enable autowiring.
Is there a clean workaround for this, my constrain is that I cannot change code at the business service side.
Each business service is part of different microservices.

Here is the piece which invokes method from kafka consumer side:
The service class and method names are obtained in the runtime from DB as a part of the configuration and it can be changed or reconfigured.
 /**call service here under try catch in catch if retry and finally persit to failure dtls**/
        try {

```
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(sdfServiceClass);


        Method consumerMethod
                = c.getDeclaredMethod(
                sdfServiceMethod, Context.class, Object.class, String.class);

        Context context_con = (Context) result[0];


        consumerMethod.invoke(c.newInstance(), context_con, result[1], messageuid_con);


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException |
            InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
```

The Business service that is being called above:

public class serviceclassA {

```
@Autowired
private JobLocator jobLocator;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sbjobLauncher")
private SimpleJobLauncher sbjobLauncher;
@Autowired
JobRepository jobRepository;
@Autowired
SbJobService sbJobService;



public void ServiceMethod(Context context, Object item, String messageUid) {
```

The problem is this class having autowirings which are not initiated by spring IOC.

Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
where the autowired class is called in business service

Answer (score 0):

solved :

Class c = Class.forName(sdfServiceClass);

```
        Object listnerClass =Class.forName(sdfServiceClass).newInstance();
        autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(listnerClass);
        Method consumerMethod
                = c.getDeclaredMethod(
                sdfServiceMethod, Context.class, Object.class, String.class);

        Context context_con = (Context) result[0];


        consumerMethod.invoke(listnerClass, context_con, result[1], messageuid_con);
```